# MKRoute shown in US only

Tags: swift, mapkit

I use `MapManager` to show the route. `MKroute` doesn't work in my country, but it does in US. Can anyone tell me if this only work in only particular countries or it does work everywhere?

Comment: Does the standard Maps app work where you live ?

Comment: Yes it works. You can check it on this framework https://github.com/varshylmobile/MapManager

Answer (score 0):

The best i can tell is that, for a route, you need a destination and starting point.

When a coordinate preferably the current user position does not have a POI in map mostly due to the fact that apple maps is not completely mapped in your place. By which i mean its besides from showing some main areas and streets, you have nothing other then this feature will not work.

If you know what i mean, then the alternative solution is Google Maps. It has a vast resource and it has information about things apple does not.

But it comes with a price, you need to learn to use Google Maps API which at this point is documented for Objective-C only.

And the callout is somewhat static in Google Maps which you can customize but the hard way.

Comment: Ok thanks..! i think apple map doesn't support in my country yet. Since it's not a well known one.

Comment: i had the same problem and i went to use Google Maps. Google Maps easy too. Its widely used than apple one so not a bad side.

Comment: yeah i hope i can afford google map too, but too bad i'm now just a college student. I can't use google map to upload my small app to AppStore for free.

Comment: Oh i don't know much about your project but it does not cost anything, just download the API and use it. Anyways, cheers.